# What Excel formula do I use to get a semi-annual date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I want a semi-annual date formula so that it shows the end of April when the date entered is between October 2018 and April 2019 and should show the end of October when the date entered is between May 2019 to October 2019.

Is there a formula to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it would be like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=DATE(2018, 10, 1),  A1<=DATE(2019, 4, 30), DATE(2019, 4, 30), 
 IF(AND(A1<=DATE(2019, 10, 30), A1>=DATE(2019, 5, 1),  DATE(2019, 10, 31), ))
```